# Configure IIS to Allow Multiple Users Simultaneous Access

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, authentication, web

I have an ASP.NET website on a WinServer2k8 machine, which is protetced through Forms Authentication. At the moment, if one person logs in on Machine A, all login attempts on Machine B will fail (A & B are using the same internet connection to access the server). The login request doesn't return any errors, rather it simply redirects back to a login screen as though the authentication never happened. I would like to know how to configure this site either through IIS7 or a web.config file so that it will allow any number of simultaneous user sessions. All of the settings for the website are set to the IIS7 defaults. I've tried changing session-state modes, the Maximum sessions property, and the Forms Authentication settings in IIS7.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. - I have also tested machines that are using a different IP Address for their internet connection and I am still unable to start a simultaneous session from that end as well.

P.P.S - If I attempt to start a session from a web browser on the server machine itself, it will work every time, regardless of who is logged in. Thoughts?

EDIT - I'm using Windows session credentials for authentication - the method used by the webpage back-end is LogonUser, which is imported from advapi32.dll

Comment: Do you have any custom authentication code that could be doing this?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I'm using Windows session credentials for authentication - the method used by the webpage back-end is LogonUser, which is imported from advapi32.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the source of my problem, and as it turns out, there was nothing wrong with the way I was using Forms Authentication.

The error, as it turns out was a timeout value for the authentication request that was too low for any machine to beat except for the very server that hosts the website. I modified the timeout value for the Forms tag in the web.config file from 5 to 5000 and that did the trick.

So what appeared to be a problem of the server mishandling sessions was actually just the inability of other machines to complete an authentication request in time. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you learn more about forms authentication details, you know that IIS/ASP.NET uses a cookie to identify whether a user has been authenticated. For load balancing scenarios, you need to enable ASP.NET session, and use out of process session mode (SQL Server mode recommended).

Only in that way, a user's session is valid across machines, and he/she can access all boxes after authenticated on one of them,

The last bit you need to pay attention to is the machine keys. For all boxes, they must use the same machine key to encrypt the session info. Otherwise, if the user is authenticated on one box, another box cannot decrypt the info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx

Comment: If I were to use the SQL Server mode, will I have to redo my authentication back-end, or will I still be able to authenticate using Windows session credentials? (see edit on original post)

Comment: I am not sure if that will work, as you are using a customized authentication provider. But usually session mode is independent of authentication.